# Portal for document management

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, document-management

I Am in search of a software for my Education Consultancy firm. So Students & candidates give their various certificates to me. I sent those abroad for their admission or job interview purpose, also they go through certain process like translation notarization etc.

I Get updates through mail or phone calls about the current situation or status of the certificates.

I am looking for a portal that can give both me and my candidates (need candidate login) their certificate's current physical position and what process has been completed and what is pending.

it would be great if its an open source